# Unable to provision hourly baremetal server using an template image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am facing error related to the RHEL Operating system price code, while trying to run the following verifyorder request for an hourly baremetal server provisioning using an existing flex image/template.

```
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server",
         "location":"DALLAS09",
         "packageId":200,
         "quantity":1,
         "presetId":93,
         "hardware":[  
            {  
               "hostname":"BM-test2",
               "domain":"ibm.com"
            }
         ],
         "useHourlyPricing":1,
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":"1800"
            },
            {  
               "id":"49759"
            },
            {  
               "id":"876"
            },
            {  
               "id":"178117"
            },
            {  
               "id":"178213"
            },
            {  
               "id":"273"
            },
            {  
               "id":"21"
            },
            {  
               "id":"37292"
            },
            {  
               "id":"906"
            },
            {  
               "id":"37278"
            },
            {  
               "id":"420"
            },
    {  
               "id":"21414"
            }
         ],
         "imageTemplateId":1401015
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using a flex image for provisioning this baremetal,( imageTemplateId":1401015) .

I want to provision  an hourly baremetal using this template, to achieve this I have provided "useHourlyPricing":1,.

The packageid and the required prices I have taken from the post request of the verify order command (when we click add to order button while ordering a device on control.softlayer.com. These all seem to be correct as no error is thrown for them).

But I am receiving following error while executing Verify Order

```
{"error":"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x (64 bit) (per-processor licensing) (21414) is not available at an hourly rate.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"}
```

I gave this price code as it is this OS which was present in the Baremetal when its flex image was captured.(I used Hardware.captureImage() method for it)

If i do not mention the OS price id, I get following error:

```
{"error":"Order is missing the following category: Operating System.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_MissingCategory"}
```

Please let me know how can I order hourly bare-metal using flex image, and what is correct operating system price id for it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the OS that you want "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x (64 bit) (per-processor licensing) (21414)" only is valid for mounthly servers. If you list the valid prices for the package 200 using this REST request:

https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[item,id, locationGroupId,hourlyRecurringFee,recurringFee]

you are going to see something like this:

```
{
        "id": 21414,
        "locationGroupId": null,
        "recurringFee": "45",
        "item": {
            "capacity": "1",
            "description": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x (64 bit) (per-processor licensing)",
            "id": 4321,
            "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
            "keyName": "OS_RHEL_6_64_BIT_PER_PROCESSOR_LICENSING",
            "softwareDescriptionId": 1247,
            "units": "N/A",
            "upgradeItemId": null,
            "itemCategory": {
                "categoryCode": "os",
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Operating System",
                "quantityLimit": 0
            }
        }
```

the "recurringFee" property is the mounthly price, an hourly price should have the "hourlyRecurringFee" property. In this case the OS you want does not have the hourly price so if you select that OS it is going to be invalid. So if you want to use that image template you need to order a mounthly server instead of hourly server.